# Firefox ignores margins, and width of all child element, with parent element that has display flex

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

Firefox ignores all the margins and width of all child elements inside a parent element which has display set to flex, and flex-direction set to column. This does  **NOT**  happen in google chrome. Is there any way to fix this, other than removing flex altogether?

```
body {  
display: flex;               
flex-direction: column;  
}
#div {
border: 1px solid green;
margin-top: 10%;
height: 100%;
}

<div id = 'div'> div </div>
```

**fiddle**

www.iscattered.com/testAll.php

[image]

Comment: Can you share a fiddle? There is probably sth missing.

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu You realize that I mentioned that this only happens in Firefox right? So why would you want me to share a fiddle?

Comment: To have a look in Firefox?

Comment: To test it easily in firefox of course?

Comment: and to have a look at your entire css & html, because here we have height:100%  of ... nothing

Comment: @frosty We cannot reproduce the issue in Firefox with the code you've shared. Unless you include enough code to reproduce the issue, this will be closed for the "no repro" close reason.

Comment: @Rein Provided link above.

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu Provided link above.

Comment: @GCyrillus 100% height of nothing...works perfectly fine in google chrome.

Comment: @TylerH You're saying that my code works perfectly fine in firefox through your testing?

Comment: @frosty yes: https://jsfiddle.net/873sdosj/ This code works exactly as it should according to the spec. By the way, a fiddle means http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @TylerH What version of firefox are you using? You're seeing a height of 100% and a margin of 10%, in firefox? Because I'm seeing a height of the word 'div' and a margin of 0.

Comment: @frosty I'm using the latest version of Firefox, 43. If you're expecting the div to be 100% the height of the viewport, that means you don't understand how height percentages work. AKA you're missing [some necessary CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/873sdosj/1/)

Comment: @TylerH I've provided a screenshot above of what it looks like to me. Also, if that is so, how come 100% height works on google chrome, just fine? If you want me to prove it, just click the link above of the image, and you'll see that i'm telling the truth.

Comment: @frosty your div's height is the same in Chrome as it is in Firefox.

Comment: @TylerH Also, I'm afraid I can't use your answer of adding height: 100% to both html, and body, as all my pages are dynamic, and height are all different according to the content.

Comment: @TylerH That's the same version I'm using. You're telling me that you went to this link https://www.iscattered.com/testAll.php in firefox and you're seeing the height of the div is 100%, and the margin is 10%? Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: @frosty No, I didn't go to the website, because questions here should include a minimal and complete code reproduction in the questions themselves, rather than just linking to an external site. We can't be expected to be intimately familiar with your server settings or environment. Hence the request for a reproduction on **http://www.jsfiddle.net**

Comment: The code provided in the question produces the exact same result in Chrome, Firefox, Opera (Presto), and IE11.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `height:100%` to both `html` and `body` selectors, everything will be alright.

Comment: Can't. Pages are dynamic, height is according to the contents inside. The most I can do is set min-height to 100%, and that wouldn't solve the problem here.

Comment: I dont understand why you cant. It can still be dynamic according to content. Did you try and see ?

Comment: Yes, of course. If I set the height of the body to 100%, and the height of contents are higher, it would overflow.

Comment: Then you could use `overflow` attribute to change it. However, if you always want to grow the size to its content, it wouldnt help either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using percentages on the div, using pixels instead worked fine in firefox.

Comment: Of course, but it prevents responsive design. But if it is not your case, just do what is easiest for you.

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu Can you explain what you mean by responsive design?

Comment: I didnt actually mean 'responsive design' here, but the dynamic margin/height which can change in different size of screens.